# How to check if a word ends with parenthesis I.e word(s) using Java and regex?

Tags: java, regex

I tried creating a regex which will help me solve the below problem but was not able to:

Example word : `mumbai(10)`

The regex should check if the word is ending with parenthesis with a value I.e `(10)` in the above word `"Mumbai(10)"`. And the value should be extracted I.e 10.

If the word is `Mum(10)bai` then no results should be the output.

Comment: Isn't it way easier just to check the chars.... `string.charAt(string.length - 1) == ')'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
String string = "mumbai(10)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*\\((\\d+)\\)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

`^` and `$` denote the beginning and end respectively. `.*` just matches anything. The parenthesis need to be escaped, since they represent a group in regular expression, which is being made use of after that. The captured group can then be extracted using `m.group(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to match:

```
\\((\\d+)\\)$
```

And extract group 1 `$1` for the value.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cD2rD8/12)

Java code:

```
String str = "mumbai(10)";
Matcher m =  Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+)\\)$").matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Explain downvote please?

Comment: Hi Karthik, the downvote is not about your answer (although there is 1 issue with it), but just because the question is about "give me the code".

Comment: @stribizhev ohh okk.. :) btw.. whats the issue? I would like to improve the answer.. thanks..

Comment: [Here is the correct code](https://ideone.com/86wdmD).

Answer (score -1):

You can try following regex,

```
\((\d+)\)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO5cG3/1)

It uses the concept of [group capture](http://regexone.com/lesson/12)